convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)^p$
I want to find all $p\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following series converges:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)^p.$$
We know $$\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n^3}.$$
Accordingly, for $p>\frac{1}{3}$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)^p\leq \frac{1}{n^{3p}},$$
so the series converges.
Now, I was wondering how to prove divergence of the series for $p\leq\frac{1}{3}$.

Hint: We have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$, this follows pretty easily from Taylor expansion. Now use limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^{3p}}$.
Of course, we are allowed to use comparison tests here because this is a series of nonnegative terms.

yea what i did , only comparision test.

@RicciTen The advantage of limit comparison (over regular comparison) is that it works in both directions. If the limit of the quotient is a positive real number then one series is convergent if and only if the other one does. And we know exactly when the series of $\frac{1}{n^{3p}}$ converges.

By the Taylor formula $\sin{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{6 n^{3}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right), \; n \to \infty$.
Hence $\frac{1}{n} - \sin{\frac{1}{n}} \sim \frac{1}{6n^3}, \; n \to \infty$. Note that $\frac{1}{n} - \sin\frac{1}{n} \geq 0$.
Therefore, by equivalence comparison test our series converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{6^{p} n^{3p}}$ converges, so if and only if $p > \frac{1}{3}$.

can you clarify the big O notation WHY IT is $O(\frac{1}{n^3})$

It is Taylor's Theorem with the Peano remainder. Look here, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

In addition, I would like to add that it is o-small instead of Big-O.

ok got it small o implies Big-O
